# Odoo 10 Enterprise cannot inherit a model create from Studio

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-enterprise

Dears,

I cannot inherit a model(settings->model) created in Odoo Studio/or from interface in a custom module (addons-custom). Example: I have a model called "x_Check" created from Odoo 10 Enterprise interface (Setting -> model), then I create a custom module and this the python class:

```
class CheckInh(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'x_Check'    
    temp = fields.Char("temp")
```

output ==>  TypeError: Model 'x_Check' does not exist in registry.

Note that inheriting a base model is working normally:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    temp = fields.Char("temp")
```

Thank you,

Platform Odoo 10 Enterprise/ Ubuntu 16.04 / Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your inherit model in manifest depend value

like

```
'depends': [
    'website',
    'x_Check',
    'product',
    'website_sale',
    'sale'
],
```